# I am a Brazilian citizen, and I want to marry a Filipino citizen. If I manage to have a work visa to work in Portugal, can she come with me?

Tags: portugal, working-visas, brazilian-citizens

I couldn't find this precise information anywhere, so I hereby ask you, is it possible for my future wife to come with me to Portugal and stay for as long as I'm working there holding a work visa?

Comment: I’m struggling to find an official source however this site indicates that if you have a Portuguese residence permit, either temporary or permanent, you can apply for family reunification visa for a spouse https://www.expatica.com/pt/visas-and-permits/family-visa-portugal-spouse-visa_944833.html. If you’re not married, the usual Schengen visitor rules /timeframe apply

Comment: Indeed, it's a difficult information. But this website seems clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve as an answer the comment from Traveller, which was presumably added on travel.stackexchange:

> I’m struggling to find an official source however [this site](https://www.expatica.com/pt/visas-and-permits/family-visa-portugal-spouse-visa_944833.html) indicates
>   that if you have a Portuguese residence permit, either temporary or
>   permanent, you can apply for family reunification visa for a spouse
>   . If you’re not married, the usual
>   Schengen visitor rules /timeframe apply